# my applications keeps stopping 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to add a spinner into my application however when I get into the page where I add the spinners I receive this error which says that my application keeps stopping, I have googled where I could find the logcat and clicked on the blue hyperlink to see where the error is at but I still don't know how to solve it.

The logcat error says:

```
2021-04-12 16:38:35.013 20187-20194/com.example.myapplication E/art: Failed sending reply to 
debugger: Broken pipe
2021-04-12 16:38:37.018 20187-20187/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 20187
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

The Activity2.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] spinnerTitles;
String[] spinnerPopulation;
int[] spinnerImages;
Spinner mSpinner;
private boolean isUserInteracting;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerTitles = new String[]{"American Pie", "Avengers Infinity War", "Avengers Endgame", "Goal I", "Goal II", "Mean Girls", "The Dark Knight", "The Dark Knight Rises", "10 Things I Hate ABout You", "Zack Snyder's Justice League"};
    spinnerPopulation = new String[]{"15 1999 ‧ Comedy/Romance ‧ 1h 36m", "12 2018 ‧ Action/Sci-fi ‧ 2h 40m", "12A 2019 ‧ Action/Sci-fi ‧ 3h 2m", "12 2005 ‧ Sport/Romance ‧ 2h 33m", "12 2007 ‧ Sport/Drama ‧ 1h 55m", "12 2004 ‧ Comedy/Teen ‧ 1h 37m", "12A 2008 ‧ Action/Adventure ‧ 2h 32m", "12A 2012 ‧ Action/Thriller ‧ 2h 44m", "12 1999 ‧ Romance/Comedy ‧ 1h 39m", "15 2021 ‧ Action/Adventure ‧ 4h 2m"};
    spinnerImages = new int[]{R.drawable.americanpie
            , R.drawable.avengersiw
            , R.drawable.avengerseg
            , R.drawable.goali
            , R.drawable.goalii
            , R.drawable.meangirls
            , R.drawable.thedarkknight
            , R.drawable.thedarkknightr
            , R.drawable.ttihay
            , R.drawable.zsjusticeleague};

    CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity2.this, spinnerTitles, spinnerImages, spinnerPopulation);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (isUserInteracting) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, spinnerTitles[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    isUserInteracting = true;
}
}
```

The Activity2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity2">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the id is correct, remember that you have to use the same layout that the view is from.

Change

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.Activity2);
```

Comment: it was actually activity_2 I had but thank you for the clue